# OIDC implementation - Upgrade from Spring boot v 1.3.5 to 2.7.1 and Spring versions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openid-connect, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to upgrade my web application that is running on Spring boot 1.3.5-Release to 2.7.1. The ultimate goal for this is to implement OIDC authentication in my web app.

The below are the current versions used

```
<spring.boot.version>1.3.5.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
<spring.version>4.1.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.integration.version>4.1.3.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>
<org.hibernate.version>4.3.10.Final</org.hibernate.version>
<aspectj.version>1.8.7</aspectj.version>
```

To implement OIDC authentication I am supposed to use OAuth2 client dependency. To use this dependency I need to use Spring Security version 5.x.x(I guess so - correct me plz). With these lower versions how can I implement the thing I wanted?

I just tried to upgrade Spring boot to 2.7.1 by resolving some multiple build issues. But finally while running the application I am getting the below error.

> 2022-10-26 21:26:31.251  INFO 14788 --- [main] o.s.core.annotation.MergedAnnotation     : Failed to introspect annotations on public org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.transactionManager(org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider): java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy

What am I missing here?? What is the minimum version of Spring and Springboot that I need to use for implementing OIDC Auth??

Comment: Remove the management for Spring, Spring Integration, Hibernate and AspectJ and use the versions as provided by Spring Boot. You are working around the Spring Boot starters/management which will result in incompatible versions on the classpath leading to all sorts of interesting issues.

Comment: @M.Deinum - "use the versions as provided by Spring Boot." >> do u suggest to use springboot starter parent ?? or how to use get the versions of those ?? this is basically a legacy web app that have "spring-boot" , "spring-boot-autoconfigure", "spring-boot-starter-test", "spring-boot-starter-jersey", "spring-boot-starter-web", "spring-boot-starter-jetty", "spring-orm", hibernate and other dependencies included separately..!!

Comment: That or use the dependency management way. The problem with manually pulling in those dependencies is you will endup with conflicting or non-compatible versions leading to weird issues. If it is legacy why use Spring Boot? The fact that web and jersey are in there probably already means there is an `@SpringBootAPplication` annotated that and thus it is a Spring Boot project (migrated from the time it was a real legacy app, but the migration is done half).

Answer (score -1):

framework Spring Authorization Server maybe better for OIDC implementation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).